# Program terminates calling thread join even though thread is joinable

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have the following code:

But for some reason, after running correctly for several iterations, the program keeps terminating during the call to join(), even though joinable() returns true right before the call to join.

I also wrapped the entire block of code for getRank() inside

```
try{
} catch(const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "Caught exception \"" << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

But no catch statement ever prints.

This is the output from running the program in slurm:

```
========= 1 =========
1
========= 1 =========
1
========= 1 =========
1
========= 1 =========
========= 2 =========
1
<<correct output for iteration 1>>
========= 3 =========
========= 2 =========
1
========= 3 =========
========= 2 =========
1
========= 3 =========
========= 2 =========
1
========= 3 =========
1
========= 1 =========
1
========= 1 =========
1
========= 1 =========
1
========= 1 =========
========= 2 =========
1
```

^ and the program ends there without any other error messages.

```
std::thread threadPool[8];


// Create threads and distribute the work across T threads
// -------------------------------------------------------------------
for (int iter = 0; iter < max_iters; iter++)
{        
    for (int i = 0; i < n_workers; i++)
    {
        threadPool[i] = std::thread(getRank, <blah...>);
        std::cout << threadPool[i].joinable() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "========= 1 =========" << std::endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n_workers; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "========= 2 =========" << std::endl;
        std::cout << threadPool[i].joinable() << std::endl;
        threadPool[i].join();
        std::cout << "========= 3 =========" << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Edit: it seems like this only happens when I lock the shared array:

```
std::mutex m; //global

void pageRank(...){
m.lock();            
shared_array[v] += (shared_array[u] / some_value);            
m.unlock();
}
```

Everything works fine if I comment out lock and unlock (but still write to the array).

here's a minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex m;

void stuff(double* sharedArr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5000; j++)
        {
            int ele = (i + j) % 10000;
            m.lock();
            sharedArr[ele] = (sharedArr[i] + 2) / 4;
            m.unlock();
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    double *sharedArr = new double[10000];
    std::thread threadPool[8];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        sharedArr[i] = 10;
    }

    for (int iter = 0; iter < 10; iter++)
    {

        std::cout << "iteration: " << iter << std::endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            threadPool[i] = std::thread(stuff, sharedArr);

            std::cout << "========= 1 =========" << std::endl;
        }  

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            std::cout << "========= 2 =========" << std::endl;            
            threadPool[i].join();
            std::cout << "========= 3 =========" << std::endl;
        }       
    }

    delete [] sharedArr;

    return 0;
}
```

Which, after running on slurm, gives the output:

```
iteration: 0
========= 1 =========
========= 1 =========
========= 1 =========
========= 1 =========
========= 2 =========
```

(Although this test code seems to work on my windows PC)

Comment: Use a debugger to eliminate the most obvious reason first, ensure that main() doesn't end before these threads are completed.

Comment: You may like to post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), this will help people help you.

Comment: Thanks, added one

Comment: I ran your code and there doesn't seem to be an issue with it. May be `slurm` kills your process because it uses a while to complete. That mutex is a bottleneck because all threads compete for it, so removing the locking makes your process complete faster.

Comment: Update: you're right, its just a resource issue.